# Individually styling date month year

Tags: functions, date, timestamp

I am using underscore_s barebone theme to build mine and came across this challenge that I would like to style date month and year separately with CSS and the code output puts them together.

I dug around and found out I can put formatting inside the following line of code (not sure if this is right way, tried everything and this worked...)

```
esc_html( get_the_date( 'd,M,Y' ) ),
```

but the output is stacked together like 8,Oct,2014 and I am failing at assigning classes to them individually. (or even outputting them separately)

full code of the segment is in functions.php and is called with `<?php mytheme_posted_on(); ?>`

```
function mytheme_posted_on() {
$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
}

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
);

$posted_on = sprintf(
    _x( '%s', 'post date', 'mytheme' ),
    '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
);

echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span>'; } endif;
```

Thank you in advance, if anyone can help me out to break down the above code and comprehend this.

Comment: The code in that function outputs content directly via the `esc_*` and `_x` functions ( and the `echo` ). There are no filters that might help you. You are basically looking at hacking the theme, which is not advisable. Additionally, questions dependent on third party code are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you can break down the date format in different parts.

```
echo '<span class="date-day">' . get_the_date( 'd' ) . '</span>';
echo '<span class="date-month">' . get_the_date( 'M' ) . '</span>';
echo '<span class="date-year">' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>';
```

Now each item have class associated with it, so you can style each differently as you require.

Comment: Use updated code. I have made changes in it and removed commas.

Comment: Thank you, I saw them later, how silly I didn't see the commas in front of me. sry. Thank you.

Comment: My final code is like this:  `<?php echo '<span class="date-day"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_date( 'd' ) . '</a></span> '; ?>  `  
`<?php echo '<span class="date-month"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_date( 'M' ) . '</a></span> '; ?>  `  
`<?php echo '<span class="date-year"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</a></span>'; ?>`

Comment: That's great! :)

Comment: after serious poking around I discovered I could also do this:  `'<span class="date-day">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'd' ) ) . '</span>' . '<span class="date-month">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'M' ) ) . '</span>' . '<span class="date-year">' . esc_html( get_the_date( 'Y' ) ) . '</span>',`  what do you think.

Comment: That's nice. But you dont need to use `esc_html` with `get_the_date` because the output will not have any html.

Comment: Thank you. I think I reached the limits of my php customization skill, I am afraid to break something, I think am going to leave it like this if there is no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Output them separate like d, then m, then year. And style them according